# Pattern matching with intermediate computation in Scala

Tags: scala

I am looking to write a simple function suffix that if you pass
1, it returns "st", 2 returns "nd" etc.

I looked at tutorial but could not find why function fails with following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: todo
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at .suffix(<console>:19)
  ... 33 elided
```

My function looks like this:

```
def suffix(n: Int): String = {
  val remainder = n % 10;

  println(remainder);

  remainder match {
    case 1 => "st";
    case 2 => "nd";
    case 3 => "rd";
    case _ => "th"
  }
}
```

I just started learning it and don't know why this function would not work since I extract last digit, match on it and return String as denoted in the function.

Comment: How do you call this function? I have tested it in a scala worksheet and it works just fine.

Comment: Ditto as @Mustafa. I ran it in REPL and worked just fine,

Comment: A `RuntimeException` with the message **todo** looks a bit like self made. And there is something *elided* ? Do you have some kind of *assert* in your code somewhere?

Comment: Well, it was a mess-up on my part. I defined a function and added a sys.error("todo") to remember to finish it. This definition was above some other functions so instead I loaded my file again and got to write function definition again at the top of the file. I wrote two functions that are the same, but forgot to delete the one with sys.error reminder. Beginner mistake..